# How to receive file from user in telegram bot?

Tags: php, laravel, bots, telegram, php-telegram-bot

i use [Telegram SDK for laravel](https://telegram-bot-sdk.readme.io/docs)

how to receive file from user ??

Comment: Do you mean, you receive a file from the user and want to do something with it, or do you want to send a file to the user?

Comment: yes ,receive a file from user and want to do something @philosopher

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I download a file or photo that was sent to my Telegram bot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31096358/how-do-i-download-a-file-or-photo-that-was-sent-to-my-telegram-bot)

Comment: is true . but i cant receive request  when user send file . just receive request when user send text . @philosopher

Answer (score 0):

if you want to receive a file from a user, have a look at this API section
https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getfile:

> Use this method to get basic info about a file and prepare it for
>   downloading

Comment: thanks. but me not receive file id!! how receive file id ?

Comment: This should be included in the received JSON.