# Download a file from Telegram using aiogram bot-framework in Python

Tags: python, file, download, telegram-bot, aiogram

How can I download a file which has been sent by a user in chat?

#### For example

I need to download the file `moonloader.log` from Telegram to my local path `C:\text-folder\moonloader.log` and read it.

#### Code so far

```py
def checkFile(path):
    if os.path.isfile(path):
        f = open(path, 'r')
        log = f.read()
        print('начинаю проверку...')
        # check log
        result = re.search('MoonLoader v.(.+) loaded.', log)
        if result:
            moonlog_version = result.group(1)
            print('• Версия moonloader: ' + moonlog_version)
            for err in range(0, len(errors)):
                for i in errors[err]:
                    print('   • Ошибка: ' + errors[err][i])

# ON RECEIVE FILE 
@dp.message_handler(content_types=types.ContentType.DOCUMENT)
async def fileHandle(message: types.File):
    await message.reply(text='файл получен, начинаю поиск ошибок...')
    ## LOAD FILE CODE
    checkFile(LOADED FILE PATH)
```

#### Updated Code

I tried to follow the [answer of hc_dev](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69122846/5730279) and added the download method. But not sure how to get the `File` or `file_path` from `message`. I tried this:

```py
def download_file(file: types.File):
    file_path = file.file_path 
    destination = r'C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\moonlog inspector\\download'
    destination_file = bot.download_file(file_path, destination) # ON RECEIVE FILE 

@dp.message_handler(content_types=types.ContentType.DOCUMENT)
async def fileHandle(message: types.Document):
    await message.reply(text='файл получен, начинаю поиск ошибок...')
    ## LOAD FILE CODE
    download_file(message.file_id)
```

But when running it raises the error:

> 'Message' object has no attribute 'file_id'

Comment: What about [`download_file()`](https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/telegram/bot.html?highlight=file#aiogram.bot.base.BaseBot.download_file) to download a file from telegram server to your local disk. This method seems a facade to [Telegram-API as guided in Downloading Files](https://core.telegram.org/api/files#downloading-files)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to save files locally, you could use [**io.BytesIO**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#binary-i-o). In my projects I am used to save files like that:

```
@dp.message_handler(content_types=['photo', 'document'])
async def photo_or_doc_handler(message: types.Message):
    file_in_io = io.BytesIO()
    if message.content_type == 'photo':
        await message.photo[-1].download(destination_file=file_in_io)
    elif message.content_type == 'document':
        await message.document.download(destination_file=file_in_io)
    # file_in_io - do smth with this file-like object
```

or with a context manager:

```
async with io.BytesIO() as file_in_io:
    await message.photo[-1].download(destination_file=file_in_io)
    file_in_io.seek(0)
    # file_in_io - do smth with this file-like object
```

Answer (score 0):

Following question welcomed and explained the new [`getFile`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getfile) operation in *Telegram Bot API*:
[How do I download a file or photo that was sent to my Telegram bot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31096358/how-do-i-download-a-file-or-photo-that-was-sent-to-my-telegram-bot/32679930#32679930)

In *aiogram* you would use [`download_file`](https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/telegram/bot.html?highlight=file#aiogram.bot.base.BaseBot.download_file) on you `Bot` object:
As parameters you can pass the string `file_path` (path identifying the file on the telegram server) and a `destination` on your local volume.

The `file_path` is an attribute of an [`types.File`](https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/telegram/types/file.html)  object.

```py
bot = # your_bot accessing Telegram's API

def download_file(file: types.File):
     file_path = file.file_path
     destination = r"C:\folder\file.txt"
     destination_file = bot.download_file(file_path, destination)
```

Comment: but how can i get file_path? can you help me?
```
def download_file(file: types.File):
    file_path = file.file_path
    destination = r'C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\moonlog inspector\\download'
    destination_file = bot.download_file(file_path, destination)

# ON RECEIVE FILE 
@dp.message_handler(content_types=types.ContentType.DOCUMENT)
async def fileHandle(message: types.Document):
    await message.reply(text='файл получен, начинаю поиск ошибок...')
    ## LOAD FILE CODE
    download_file(message.file_id)
```
'Message' object has no attribute 'file_id'