# How to download files to my server using telegram bot API in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, telegram, telegram-bot, node-telegram-bot-api

I need to download big files(1gb) which are sent to my bot by telegram users. I had rented a server to run the bot but i am not able to find a way to download the files to my server. Please can any of you help me with my problem.

Comment: I think this answer would help you
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31096358/how-do-i-download-a-file-or-photo-that-was-sent-to-my-telegram-bot

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.