# Ruby - How download to my computer the photo sent by the user to the telegram bot?

Tags: ruby, telegram-bot

I am using Ruby for my telegram bot. People send some information to bot, and some times it is photo. I Need to save this photo to my computer in directory with Ruby file and then send this photo another people if he or she is needed of it.

So,  How do I download a photo that was sent to my Telegram bot? I know about getFile from official site of Telegram and about this question [How do I download a file or photo that was sent to my Telegram bot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31096358/how-do-i-download-a-file-or-photo-that-was-sent-to-my-telegram-bot) but i don't understand how to use it with Ruby, because i'm start ruby only 5 months ago.
I try to wrote different code, but all doesn't work...

```
bot.messages_handler(content_types=['photo'])
bot.send_message(message.chat_id,bot.get_file_url(message.photo[0].file_id))
```

I'm hope for your help.

UPDATE!
So, now after codding and analisis all information and answer I have code which can find 'file_id' of photo from message of user and use this 'file_id' for sending this photo to another users.

```
if message.photo
  info_about_phot = message.photo.to_s #Hash all info about photo to string
  for i in ((info_about_phot.index('@file_id="')+10).. 
      (info_about_phot.index('", @file_unique_id=')-1)) #find all simbols of 'file_id' inside info about photo
      info_about_phot = info_about_phot + message.photo.to_s[i] #mabe 'file_id from all simbols'
   end
end
bot.api.send_photo(chat_id: message.from.id, photo: info_about_phot) #send message with only photo
```

may be it is not so clear as variant of @mechnicov but it works perfect and help me with my problem. But if some body can write better code - i will say "Thanks!!!".

Comment: What gem did you use?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify used gem

Just as example using [telegram-bot-ruby](https://github.com/atipugin/telegram-bot-ruby)

You can pass [photo](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#photosize) file_id from [message](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#message) to [`getFile`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getfile) method and get [file](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#file) information, that has `file_path` attribute

```
photo_url = bot.api.get_file(message.photo.last.file_id).file_path
```

It is photo URL. After that you can download file different ways with Ruby, for example

```
require "open-uri"

io = URI.open(photo_url)
File.open(path_to_save, 'w') { |f| f.write(io.read) }
```

Comment: Thanks for wanting to help
I use ruby-2.7.2
after you answer i try to use your code and now have this eror

undefined method `file_id' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Comment: @Max it means there is no photo in that message

Comment: thanks you for help, after you answer i analised it and wrote code which helped me. I wrote it also in the top question.